# The endpoint is not compatible when creating endpoint Traffic Manager profile

Tags: azure, azure-traffic-manager

Failed to save Traffic Manager profile changes Failed to save configuration changes to Traffic Manager profile 'xxxx'. Error: Profiles in the 'Default-TrafficManager' resource group must be compatible with the Azure Service Management (ASM) API. They may not contain PublicIpAddress endpoints or endpoints in a different subscription than that of the profile. The endpoint 'xxxx' is not compatible.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 1):

When Traffic Manager is created using Resource Group named "Default-TrafficManager" it is considered ASM and trying to configure some features result in error message. You cannot create a Traffic Manager profile in a Resource Group named Default-TrafficManager with any ARM-only features. This is due to a hard-coded internal limitation that any ATM profile in a Resource Group named Default-TrafficManager must be compatible with the Azure Service Management (ASM) APIs.

To resolve this issue, you need to move your Azure Traffic manager to a new Resource Group that is NOT named "Default-TrafficManager".

Refer the following article on how to move your ATM to another resource group : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-resource-group-and-subscription#use-the-portal

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using some "classic" ASM resources.  Are your endpoints classic virtual machines or cloud services?  I believe traffic manager does support these but all endpoints have to be in the same subscription.  There may also be an issue with mixing ASM and ARM resources so the solution is probably to migrate your ASM resources to ARM.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/migration-classic-resource-manager-overview